# Ubuntu server 12.10 /dev/sda1 disk full

Tags: disk-usage

My server `/dev/sda1` disk full

```
root@server:/var/www# df 
Filesystem 1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda1   48060296  45653236         0 100% / 
udev         8055724        12   8055712   1% /dev 
tmpfs        3225816      1140   3224676   1% /run 
none            5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock 
none         8064536       144   8064392   1% /run/shm 
/dev/sda3  908566268 580691288 281722432  68% /home
```

Previously when I perform `apt-get autoclean & clean` I can solve the issue by clear some space. But this time it's not working.

I wish to know which directory under `/dev/sda1` but I couldn't check on it. How should I do? Which directory I should look into it and delete those folder?

Having `/dev/sda1` full has jammed up MySQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't have partitioned your hard drive that way. You partition it that way when you'll have a few system files and applications accessible to all users on one small partition (`/`) and per-user data on the other very large partition (`/home`). In other words, it's for standard desktop use.

You have a MySQL server that stores huge database files, which don't fit anywhere in that scheme. In other words, you have a server that's not run by a particular real user, not purely a standard desktop.

You should probably repartition, either to merge the `/` and `/home` partitions (the best option to avoid this sort of thing) or to increase the proportion allocated to the `/` partition.

---

With that out of the way, use BleachBit.

## Use BleachBit from the Universe repository:

#### Turn off MySQL

1. Open up a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following:

   ```
   sudo service mysql stop
   ```

#### Free up some space by removing unneeded and still-packed software and by removing archived log files:

1. Open up a terminal and run the following:

   ```
   sudo -i
   apt-get autoremove --purge
   apt-get autoclean
   apt-get clean
   rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*
   find /var/log -name '*.gz' -delete
   ```

#### Turn on the Universe repository through Synaptic Package Manager

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager.
2. `Settings` menu > `Repositories`.
3. Make sure `Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)` is checked.
4. Click `Close`.
5. Exit Synaptic Package Manager.

#### Fix things because you're using an unsupported release (12.10)

1. Only follow this section if you're using [a release that's so old that it's no longer supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_life).
2. Open up a terminal and run the following:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. Replace everything that has the pattern `http://whatever/ubuntu` with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit.

#### Install BleachBit

1. Open up a terminal and run the following:

   ```
   sudo -i
   apt-get update
   apt-get install bleachbit
   ```

#### Run BleachBit as root

1. Open the applications menu (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).
2. `System Tools` menu > `BleachBit (as root)`.
3. Clean a bunch of stuff.

#### Turn on MySQL

1. Open up a terminal and run the following:

   ```
   sudo service mysql start
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your root filesystem is full (a bit hard to read the output of df - try use `df -BM` for the disk usage in megabytes rather than bytes). The root filesystem is mounted on `/dev/sda1` which refers to a physical device - in this case a hard disk.  Directories under `/` which can take up space are `/var` and `/tmp` (and others) - `/tmp` should clear on a reboot but log files in `/var` can occupy space

try `du -sh /directory_name` to get the size of each directory to see which is taking up most space

For example `du -sh /var`

Comment: Better even than `df -BM` is `df -h`, which will choose an appropriate human-readable unit for each figure.

Comment: I  find the max-depth parameter of du  very useful . `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /`to begin with and then dig into the directory that takes up the most space for example:   `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var`

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this answer as a last resort** due to the likelyhood that you already done this.

Try clear out any old kernels with `sudo apt-get autoremove` then check your disk usage again.